# How to display data and address in nasm 64-bit?

Tags: nasm

I am doing a practical assignment. And I have made an array and I want to display data and address simultaneously in the format (`address: data`). How to do that? What changes do I need to do in my code? How to use rsi again for displaying address?
The link to my code is:
http://rextester.com/AQMJ86771

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is not good practice to do assignments for someone, but because you're so close, I'll endulge

```
    %macro disp 2
        push    rsi
        push    rcx
        mov rax,1
        mov rdi,1
        mov rsi,%1
        mov rdx,%2
        syscall

        pop    rcx
        pop    rsi
    %endmacro

    section .data
        msg1 db "Menu : ",10
             db "1.NOWOS",10
             db "2.NOWS ",10
             db "3.OWOS ",10
             db "4.OWS  ",10
        l1 equ $-msg1
        newline db 0AH
        colon db ' : '
        src dq 01H,02H,03H,04h,05h
        dst dq 00h,00h,00h,00h,00h

    section .bss
        buff resb 16
        pcount resb 1
        ncount resb 1

    section .code
    global _start
    _start:
        disp msg1,l1
        mov rsi,src
        mov rcx,5
    back:
        mov     rax, rsi
        call    disp16num
        disp    colon, 3
        lodsq
        call    disp16num
        disp    newline,1
        loop    back

        mov rax,60
        mov rdi,0
        syscall

    disp16num:
       push    rcx
       push    rsi
       mov     rsi, buff
       mov     rcx, 16
       mov     rbx, rax
    back1:
       rol rbx,4
       mov al,bl
       and al,0FH
       cmp al,09H
       jbe add30
       add al,7H
    add30:
        add al,30H
        mov [rsi],al
        inc rsi
        loop back1
        disp buff,16
        pop     rsi
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

Which will give you this output.

Menu : 
1.NOWOS
2.NOWS 
3.OWOS 
4.OWS  
00000000006001B4 : 0000000000000001
00000000006001BC : 0000000000000002
00000000006001C4 : 0000000000000003
00000000006001CC : 0000000000000004
00000000006001D4 : 0000000000000005